# I am no longer able to see the cursor

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am running T.T. 16.04. As I was opening Pokerth to play I inadvertently clicked on the maximize button when the screen was already maximized, expanding it to the point where I cannot see the radio buttons or the edge of the desktop(clock, off button, etc). I cannot grab the screen with my mouse anywhere and pull it into frame, I have tried every variation of ctrl-F buttons, ctrl-alt-F buttons, ctrl-alt-shift-you get the picture, and after three days I got bupkis. I started with Seattle DOS 3.0 where everything was keystroked so I have a fairly large memory bank from which to draw on and nothing. mike.

Comment: What is T. T.? add more information to your question. And remember, we can't shoot you even if we want :)

Comment: @Anwar - I suppose that T.T. is Trusty Tahr.

Comment: @CristianaNicolae I thought same, but then 16.04 is a contradiction. Trusty is 14.04

Comment: @Anwar - Oh! Indeed! I haven't noticed the contradiction. Maybe it's a typo.

Comment: Super (Win-key) + Arrow key will snap the window to a certain edge. Similar to Aero Snap.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then the letter <kbd>M</kbd> and then keep pressing the <kbd>↓</kbd> until you see the top of the window appearing.

If that doesn't help, try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.  That'll just close the window.